# How do I populate a table in Javascript by clicking a button using the onClick() function?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, javascript-framework

Using JavaScript, I want to populate the numbers in soduku.setstring(); into a table once a user clicks the button "Easy". How can I achieve this using the onClick() function?

```
function initialize() {
var col, row;
for (row = 0; row <=8; row++) {
for (col=0; col <= 8; col++) {
var cell = document.getElementById('cell_' + col + '_' + row);
if (!parseInt(cell.innerHTML)) {
// cell is empty
cell.onclick = selectCell;
cell.className = 'tofill';
}
}
}
document.onkeypress = keyPress;
}

function easygame(){

    var sudoku.setString("240057360000008009378000200060041702080000005000005010130000000050003026000812000");
    loadPuzzle(sudoku);
    updateUI();
}

function updateUI(){
    initialize();

}


<input type="button" value="Easy" onclick="easygame()"/>
<table align=center id="sudoku" cellspacing=0>
<tr>
<td id="cell_0_0"></td>
<td id="cell_1_0"></td>
<td id="cell_2_0"></td>
<td id="cell_3_0"></td>
<td id="cell_4_0"></td>
<td id="cell_5_0"></td>
<td id="cell_6_0"></td>
<td id="cell_7_0"></td>
<td id="cell_8_0"></td>
<tr>
```

Comment: You'll get a better response from people if you post some code that you've tried instead of just asking how to do it. The question we want you to ask is "How can I *fix* this?"

Comment: Find the table by id, then loop through its td elements and put the related array value in them

Comment: @sachleen Well so far I had been manually typing the values for each cell but then I just thought it would be easier to have a button that allows users to click. and once clicked a function loads numbers into the table in each cell. I just don't know how to approach the problem from a scripting point of view in Javascript.

Comment: @user1883386 : Of course we will be able to help you if your code is not working. But we cant write codes from scratch for you. Try something and post it here.

Comment: @T0X1C I have created an initialisation process that takes place on load and looks through all the cells in the table. However, I tried to create an update function that pretty much does the same thing but the purpose is that, once a user clicks the Easy button, the easygame() function will be active and then the update will take place after. The problem is that that is not happening. Any help?

Answer (score -1):

For a sudoku, why dont you use 2D arrays. its logically more easier rather than using string. As far as your question goes, you could use jQuery to fill in the table like this,

```
for(var i=0;i<81;i++)
{
    $('table#sudoku td:eq('+i+')').text(sudokuString[i]);   
}
```